# Лицензирование программы с привязкой к железу

Tags: delphi, лицензирование

Есть моя программа, которую я хочу отдавать пользователям.
Программа читает зашифрованные мной файлы и выводит в нормальном виде пользователю.
Нужно сделать привязку к железу.
Мне интересен ход действий при лицензировании. Поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это очень субъективный вопрос? Методика защиты приложения зависит от многих факторов, например: есть ли сервер, на который приложение может обратиться за проверкой лицензии или за самими файлами? Как вообще Вы видите (абстрактно) порядок работы пользователя по установке приложения и работе с ним, применительно к защите файлов? Т.е. для каких-либо ответов нужно знать предполагаемую модель распространения приложения.

Comment: привязка к железу это плохая идея, много раз хотел отрезать яйца разработчикам которые это сделали, ибо на ответственном участке при выходе из строя ты просто теряешь то за что заплатил немалые деньги , хотите нормальной защиты и удобства для пользователей, применяйте USB токен

Comment: В этом случае нецелесообразно экономически использовать токен. Не тот уровень по.

Comment: Если вы не очень хорошо разбираетесь в программировании (судя по остальным вашим вопросам), то лучше для защиты использовать какое-нибудь готовое ПО. Потому что в противном случае вы можете потратить месяц на реализацию защиты, которую более-менее грамотный крекер потом обойдёт одним NOPом.

Comment: Если бы мне нужно было готовое ПО , я бы купил готовое ПО. И судя по вашему ответу человеку который как по вашим словам не разбирается в программировании и не нужно дальше разбираться, а брать готовое. Вопрос был о том как привязать ПО к железу или услышать ответ разбирающихся в программировании людей.

Comment: @gregor, Мой ответ был про то, что нужно отделять мух от котлет. Если вы хотите научиться делать лицензионную защиту и привязку к железу - это одно. Если, как следует из вашего вопроса, вам требуется "вотпрямщяс" защитить готовое приложение и начать его продавать, то быстрее и надёжнее взять готовое ПО.

Comment: Там же написано, что привязка к железу. Про "вотпрямщяс" и "быcтрее" это вам явно показалось. Если вы предлагаете готовое ПО, то какое(платное/бесплатно). ?Ваш ответ из разряда "загугли , чувак". Программа на 3 копейки не стоит того, чтобы сильно заморачиваться, да и услуги хакера будут гораздо дороже

Answer (score 5):

Информацию о железе можно получить через классы *WMI*.
Если делать привязку, то можно пользоваться серийным номером *HDD* и его моделью.
Полученные данные можно зашифровать, сохранить в файл, попросить пользователя отправить  вложением по почте.
На основе этих данных можно сгенерировать ключ, прислать его пользователю. При регистрации прописать в файл или в реестр.
При запуске программы проверять его наличие.
Если ключа нет, то программа не запускается, если ключ есть, то декодировать его, узнать железо и сравнить с установленным.

Comment: Ответ хороший, плюсанул. Но хочу обратить особое внимание на то, что 1. Защита должна соответствовать защищаемому продукту. Запросто окажется, что стоимость внедрения защиты выше стоимости самого продукта. 2. Защита должна быть адекватной. Это значит, что она не должна мешать пользователю. Простой пример - 1с на сервере в режиме программной эмуляции (hyper-v, esxi или подобное). Меняем размер винчестера (виртуального!!!!) - требуется переактивация. Защита не должна глючить. Например, в ситуации, если есть привязка к серийнику диска, а их в системе два. И т.п. соображения

Comment: Гипотетически можно, например, привязаться к серийному номеру операционной системы, благо его можно из реестра цепануть... Ну, и надеяться, что пользователь не будет ее переустанавливать каждый день

Comment: Полностью согласен, я бы защиту делал максимально простой. Пока программа не широко распространена её мало кто будет ломать. А вот из-за того, что нет нужного функционала или плохое юзабилити больше вероятность того, что пользователь не купит.

Comment: 1. Вопрос к чему цепляться. Дешёвые китайские мамки через WMI могут не отдавать информацию ('To be filled by OEM' в ответ на запрос о производителе, например).

Comment: 2. 'если ключа нет, то программа не запускается' т.е. обычный `if not licensed then ExitProgram;` обходится на раз заменой пары байт в exe-шнике. Гораздо надёжнее зашифровать какие-нибудь, требуемые для работы программы, константы в исходном коде, а в качестве лицензионного ключа использовать ключ для дешифрации, в свою очередь зашифрованный каким-нибудь ID железа + Random Salt. А регистрацию проверять по контрольной сумме расшифрованных констант. Хотя такой способ тоже обходится, но сложнее.

Comment: 3. Привязываться к ID операционки - плохая идея, т.к. при переустановке Windows регистрации слетит, а при клонировании на другой компьютер - останется.

Comment: @ Alekcvp Вот именно . Некоторое железо не содержит данных о серийном номере и др. Хотелось бы узнать комбинацию свойств Win32 классов(из WMI) которые гарантировано содержат информацию и давали бы уникальный ID ссистемы

Comment: Жесткий диск содержит серийник, именно поэтому я его и предложил, в принципе его и достаточно, если брать системный диск. Можно не серийник материнки использовать, а наименование материнки и проца.  Кому надо взломают, но глюков с системой защиты быть не должно. Человек заплатит деньги и будет неделю или две на саппорте висеть, чтобы у него заработал купленный ключ?  Не захочет ли он отозвать платёж?

Comment: Лучше усилия вложить в продвижение софта и функционал, чем в разработку неприступной защиты. Честные люди купят по достойной цене, несмотря на наличие кряка, а те кто хочет халявы все равно не станет покупать, хотя и нахватает на файлопомойках вирусов. И никто не гарантирует, что хакер при помощи взломанной программы, что-то не хорошее не сделает :)

Comment: @  Albert Fomin `Win32_PhysicalMedia` дает серный номер системного диске? или нужно сначала узнать id системного диска а потом как-то использовать его в запросе с `Win32_PhysicalMedia`. Если в системе несколько HDD

Comment: Тут всё достаточно извращенно     'select caption from Win32_volume where systemvolume=True'   - вернет системный диск, случается, что операционка не на *c:* установлена.  Затем через    'SELECT Dependent,Antecedent FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition' найти имеется ли в свойстве *Dependent* имя системного диска,   Antecedent - для этой записи будет содержать имя раздела.  Затем 'SELECT Dependent,Antecedent FROM win32_diskdrivetodiskpartition' вернет в Antecedent уже значение индекса диска. А уже после этого можно сделать запрос SELECT * FROM win32_Physicalmedia where tag like '%physicaldrive0%'

Comment: Можно запросы тестировать через *WBEMTest.exe*